# How to Display Android Native Alertdialog on App Load Without Showing Anything Else

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to display a native Alertdialog as soon as the app loads, but an ad is showing before that. I want to make sure this Alertdialog is showing as the first thing when the app loads, and when the Alertdialog is dismissed, the ads and everything else should load next.

Any ideas on how to do that inside Android application?

Here's what I have in code:

```html
 public void checkForCookiePolicy()
  {
   final SharedPreferences settings =
           getSharedPreferences("localPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
       if (settings.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true)) {
       
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
     builder1.setTitle("Cookie Policy");
     builder1.setMessage("We use device identifiers to personalise content and ads, to provide social media features and to analyse our traffic. We also share such identifiers and other information from your device with our social media, advertising and analytics partners.");
     builder1.setCancelable(true);

     builder1.setPositiveButton("See Details",
       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
         
         Intent intent = new Intent(AppActivity.this, CookiePolicy.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         settings.edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();
        
        }
       });
     builder1.setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       settings.edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();
       dialog.cancel();
       
      }
     });

     AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
     alert11.show();
       }
     
  }
```

Here's the ad code. It's above the alert code:

```html
  revmob = RevMob.start(this);
  revmob.createFullscreen(this, null);
```

Comment: You'd need to show us the code displaying your ads.  We have no idea how you're doing that, so we have no idea how to stop them from displaying.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, I do not want to stop the ads. I want to show the ads after the alert is dismissed. It's kind of a priority. Alert shows, nothing else.

Comment: You still need to show us that part of the code.  We have no idea what you're doing other than showing a dialog.  You aren't giving us enough context to actually help.

Comment: Ok, edited the post. @Gabe Sechan. The alert is showing first, but the Revmob full screen displays on top of the alert. I want Revmob to be displayed after the alert is dismissed.

Comment: Set dismiss listener to the dialog . In that listener start your ad

Comment: @karthik kolanji, there's dismiss button on the dialog, but it has to do with the alert dialog, not the ad itself. Is there a way to set the alert to show first as a priority and block all other activities / classes and code that loads as soon as the app starts?

Comment: I do not want anything to overlay the Alert Dialog. Game Center login is starting, as well as Revmob Full Screen Ad. Everything should be suspended and only the alert should load up, until dismissed and everything else should load afterwards.

Comment: The alert code above has a stand alone java class, called "CookiePolicy.java" a code I did not shared here. This " public void checkForCookiePolicy();" function is in AppActivity.java.

Comment: "Alertdialog is showing as the first thing when the app loads, and when the Alertdialog is dismissed, the ads and everything else should load next." Writing ur ad starting code on dialog dismiss listener will help u .

Comment: @ karthik kolanji, how to do that. Propose a solution to test?